# Problem with primeNG chart: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, primeng

I have problems with a PrimeNG chart.

At the beginning my problem was with in the html with the [options], I read that it was better if I downloaded the 2.9.4 chart.js and I did it, now I have the error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto' in 'D:\Proyectos trabajo\Plots\node_modules\primeng\fesm2015'

I read that it is related with the way I have to import the v2, but I dont understand the right way, I am trying to use this:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
```

but I have one error in 'chart.js', well here is my code:

the module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { PlotsRoutingModule } from './barChart-routing.module';
import { BarPageComponent } from './pages/bar-page/bar-page.component';
import { BarChartComponent } from './components/bar-chart/bar-chart.component';
import { BarFormComponent } from './components/bar-form/bar-form.component';
import {ChartModule} from 'primeng/chart'; //IS HERE WHERE THE PROBLEM IS??? I tryed to change it for import Chart from 'chart.js' but I have an error

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BarPageComponent,
    BarChartComponent,
    BarFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PlotsRoutingModule,
    ChartModule
  ]
})
export class PlotsModule { }
```

the component imports:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AppConfig } from 'src/app/plots/interfaces/interfaces';
import { AppConfigServiceService } from 'src/app/plots/services/app-config-service.service';
```

the angular.json

```
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"
            ]
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Why are you trying to `import Chart from 'chart.js'`? Using PrimeNg you might want to use their wrapper `p-chart`

Comment: I've found `import * as Chart from 'chart.js';` in one of my old projects, can you try this?

Comment: In the html I am using p-chart in this way: <p-chart type="bar" [data]="basicData" [options]="basicOptions"></p-chart>

Comment: what version of primeng do you have installed? primeng 13 is working with chartjs ^3

Comment: Using      import * as Chart from 'chart.js'; I get this error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'chart.js'.

Comment: I am using PrimeNG 13.0.4  should I change it??

Comment: Try installing the types for chart.js `npm install --save-dev @types/chart.js`

Comment: @Daniela Gonzalez follow the instructions here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chart and install the supported version 3.3.2 of chattjs

Comment: I did this:   `npm install --save-dev @types/chart.js`   but I have the same error...... At the beginning I followed the primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chart but I had errors with the options, that is the reason I moved to version 2.9.4 of chart.js

Comment: Hey guys... It is working now.... I uninstalled chart.js 2.9.4 and installed again the current version and it is working... I dont know why but it works.... thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the version of angular you are using. Chart.js was updated to 3.3.2 in primeng 12.1.0

Follow this link for the migration guide
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Migration-Guide#1210

If you have any customized classes which use chart.js you may need to have a look at this too https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html